# About identity of a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, monoid

This question is from Jonathan D. H. Smith's Introduction to Abstract Algebra book.

> The question basically says that for an infinite set $X$ a function  $f : X \to X$ is called *almost identical* if the set $\left\{ x \in X \mid x \neq f\left(x\right) \right\}$ of elements $x$ of $X$, differing from their image $f(x)$ under $f$, is finite. If $F$ be a subset of $X^X$ consisting of almost identical functions, show that $F$ is a monoid of functions.

So I think I have shown that $F$ is a semi-group of functions. But, I am confused about showing that an identity exists in $F$ because for all $x$ in $X$, $\operatorname{id}(x)$ = $x$. Does that mean that the set of elements $x$ of $X$ differing from their image $\operatorname{id}(x)$ under $\operatorname{id}$ is empty and hence finite?

This is very confusing to me. Can somebody provide a hint? Thank you a lot.

Comment: The empty set is finite.

Comment: That I knew. Is the reasoning that leads to the conclusion strong enough?

Comment: Your reasoning is exactly correct. Your LaTeX could be better, though (see the revision log) :)

Answer (score 1):

A set $S$ is said to be finite if $S$ is empty or there exists a bijection $S \rightarrow I_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $I_n = \{ 1, 2, ..., n \}$.